# why do we have to use colon (:) in the route parameter "/:userQuery"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parameters, routes

why do we have to use  colon (:)  in the route parameter "/:userQuery"

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.listen(3000);
app.get("/:userQuery", (req, res) => {
  res.render("about", {
    title: "about page",
    data: { userQuery: req.params.userQuery },
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation? Did you try to remove it and see what happens? https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: if i remove colon then it throws error - Cannot GET /about

Comment: So there is your answer.... ;) You use the colon because it denotes a route parameter. Read that section in the guide.

Answer (score -1):

```
app.get("/info/:parameter/test", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.parameter);
});
```

So if you now access https://localhost/info/abc/test, the console log will now log `abc`.

This is to why you can do /about/userhere in your case.
For the case of removing the :, and getting the error cannot get /about. That's because it's now `/userQuery`, but obviously req.params.userQuery will be undefined now.